# contents of map file - details(VS 2008 / VS 2010)

Tags: visual-studio, linker, map-files

Is there any detailed documentation / information for the contents of map files? I have a rough idea, but some elements are not apparent to me, and google didnät help either.

Examples:

```
 0001:00000000 <decorated name>  00401000 f i CMDevNode.obj
 0001:0000c870 <decorated name>  0040d870 f   uafxcw:afxmem.obj
 ...                                          CIL library: CIL module
```

What is the "f" and "i"?  Are there other flags like these?

The lib:obj probably refers to a DLL/static library?

What is the "CIL library: CIL module" - that seems to be code generated by the compiler.

TIA

Comment: out of curiosity, what are you doing with that info?

Comment: I want to bring that into a format that's easier searchable / drillable, and I wonder what kind of information I am missing

Comment: The linker map is use when debugging the stack dump from a crash. I've not needed the "f i" information before, but now I'm looking at eight different functions mapped to the same address. Does not make sense.